# R use foreach with nested for loops

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, parallel-processing, nested-loops

I have been trying to use the `foreach` package to parallelize my (admittedly inefficient) nested-for loop simulations, but have had no luck figuring out what the correct syntax of the `foreach` loop is for my code. The example below (although nonsensical) illustrates the general form of my simulations:

```
results.ls <- list()
listcount <- 1
variableOnePara.v <- c("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma")
variableTwoPara.v <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
function1.fn <- function(variableOne.s) {
  df1 <- data.frame( a = variableOne.s, b = Sys.time() )
  return(df1)
}
function2.fn <- function(df1, variableTwo.s) {
  df <- data.frame(cbind(df1, variableTwo.s))
  return(df)
}

for(i in 1:length(variableOnePara.v)) {
  for(j in 1:length(variableTwoPara.v)) {

    variableOne.s <- variableOnePara.v[i]
    variableTwo.s <- variableTwoPara.v[j]
    df1 <- function1.fn(variableOne.s)
    df <- function2.fn(df1, variableTwo.s)

    results.ls[[listcount]] <- df
    listcount <- listcount + 1
  }
}
results.df <- do.call(rbind, results.ls) ## a dataframe of the results
```

Essentially, what one simulation does is take a series of inputs, run them through a bunch of functions, and spit out a 1-row dataframe at the end. I then place this data frame in a list, and start the next simulation with the next series of inputs (hence the nested loops). I am trying to parallelize this process. (Note that the starting inputs are exogenous and do not depend on the results of a previous calculation).

I guess what I am looking for is the correct syntax so that:

1. The `foreach` loop "master" sends out the code below with different inputs (generated from the nested for loops) to different "workers"
2. The "workers" run the actual functions to generate the final dataframe, which then gets placed in `results.ls`
3. The "master" collects all the separate *results.ls* and combines them to one big list.

I have tried replacing the first for loop with `foreach` (so `foreach(i = 1:3)`) and tried placing an outer `foreach` loop with `i=1:12` (i.e., number of total iterations) but that didn't work either.

Could someone show me how to correctly use a `foreach` loop with the above nested for-loop structure? Thank you very much.

Comment: You should first try to make it work ... ` df1 <- function(variableOne.s)` is not a complete expression, it can't work.

Comment: Please show what you've tried and provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this??

```
results.df = foreach(i = 1:length(variableOnePara.v),
        .combine = rbind) %:% 
  foreach(j = 1:length(variableTwoPara.v),
          .combine = rbind) %dopar% 
  {
    variableOne.s <- variableOnePara.v[i]
    variableTwo.s <- variableTwoPara.v[j]
    df1 <- function1.fn(variableOne.s)
    df <- function2.fn(df1, variableTwo.s)
    return(df)

  }
```

Result is shown below :

```
> results.df
       a                   b variableTwo.s
1  Alpha 2019-07-15 14:21:16             1
2  Alpha 2019-07-15 14:21:16             2
3  Alpha 2019-07-15 14:21:16             3
4  Alpha 2019-07-15 14:21:16             4
5   Beta 2019-07-15 14:21:16             1
6   Beta 2019-07-15 14:21:16             2
7   Beta 2019-07-15 14:21:16             3
8   Beta 2019-07-15 14:21:16             4
9  Gamma 2019-07-15 14:21:16             1
10 Gamma 2019-07-15 14:21:16             2
11 Gamma 2019-07-15 14:21:16             3
12 Gamma 2019-07-15 14:21:16             4
```